# Swipe between two UIViewControllers' views

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swipe

I know I have asked this question a couple of times, but I'm very inexperienced and don't think I've been given the right answer yet.

I now have two view controllers, each with a .h file, a .m file, and a .xib file. In both the .xib files, I have a UIView. How can I make it so that you can swipe between these two views? For example, the app opens on the first view, then you swipe from the right to the left and the next view appears. I want the animation of the swiping to be like that of the Photos app when swiping through photos.

Answer (score 17):

While you could implement this yourself (with [custom container view controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) in conjunction with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or `UIScrollView`), if using iOS 6 and later, the easiest way will be to use a [Page View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3) with "scroll" transition style.

Consider this storyboard:

[image: pageviewcontroller storyboard]

It consists of a page view controller, and two scenes for two pages. Page 1 has a storyboard identifier of `one` and a base class of `PageOneViewController`. Page 2 has a storyboard identifier of `two` and a base class of `PageTwoViewController`.

I then wrote a `UIPageViewController` subclass (and, perhaps obvious, this is the class I specified for the first scene of the above storyboard), which has the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSource = self;

    [self setViewControllers:@[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"one"]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[PageOneViewController class]])
        return nil;

    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"one"];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[PageTwoViewController class]])
        return nil;

    return [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"two"];
}
```

You could do this with NIBs, too, but it requires writing more code. If you search for `UIPageViewController XIB` and you'll probably get some hits.

If you need to support iOS versions prior to 6.0, you'll have to do the custom container approach with pan gesture or scroll view.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of right ways to to rich your goal.

For example:

1) From iOS 6 you can use [`UIPageViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)  with transitionStyle  property `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`

2) You can use `UIScrollView` with property `pagingEnable = YES;` and add your views inside it. Also you will need to implement all containers methods   `addChildViewController:`, `removeFromParentViewController`, `willMoveToParentViewController:`, `didMoveToParentViewController:` to deal with with appear/disappear mathods of your controllers

3) you can find third-party solution like:

- [TTScrollSlidingPagesController](https://github.com/TomThorpe/UIScrollSlidingPages)
- [PagerViewController](https://github.com/morodomi/PagerViewController)

Comment: Could you possibly help me out with the scroll view option. As I said, I'm not very good with Objective-C so I don't really know what I'm doing. Could you possibly write some example code of how I could implement the UIScrollView. Again, as i said before, i have two view controllers (I don't know if that is right), with a single view inside of each of them. Thank you! Please ask for more info if you need it!

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials and samples in internet: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/ http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2012/02/page-control-display-view-controllers.html http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/

Comment: @user2397282 Flop has given you a lot of excellent links. You should go through some (if not all) of those and really understand how they work. If you take the time to research your question by going through some of these links, you'll discover a couple of great approaches in solving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great repo for this:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwipeController

You basically need a UIPageViewController and put your ViewControllers inside that.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this repo .It is so much simpler and easily understandable for RnD. (Swift 3 code)

https://github.com/lakshikabhardwaj/LBViewControllerCollection

```
     let mainViewController = CPPageMenuVC(nibName: "CPPageMenuVC", bundle: nil)
      let pageMenuarray :[PageModal] = [PageModal(pageTitle: "Cat", pageVC: cpCatVC),PageModal(pageTitle: "Cow", pageVC: cowCX),PageModal(pageTitle: "Chat", pageVC: cpCatVC),PageModal(pageTitle: "ElephantElephant", pageVC: elephantVC)]

      pageMenuVC.pageArray = pageMenuarray
      pageMenuVC.tabHeight = 0    // WITHOUT TOPICS
```