# iOS dual view controllers scroll together on a page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Sorry I'm new to Objective c / iOS dev.

So I have two view controllers displaying separate views on one iOS page written in objective C. 
[image: Two view controllers]

View 1 is a static page. View 2 is a scrollable list (UICollectionViewDataSource) that I plan to implement an infinite scroll in.

Right now view 1 scrolls up and down as expected. View 2 sometimes depending on how you tap the screen scrolls as one with view 1 (they both go up and down together) and it sometimes scrolls under view controller 1. How can I create a permanent behavior where they scroll together? I want them to move as if they are connected (as if I were scrolling through a web page that had a table that I could scroll down through).

I searched around (I may be using the wrong search terms) but everything I see has to do with switching between two or more view controllers. (ex [Swipe between two UIViewControllers' views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047387/swipe-between-two-uiviewcontrollers-views))

In case it is unclear I want the following behavior:

Original Page:

```
xxx
xyx
xxx
111
222
```

Scroll down:

```
xyx
xxx
111
222
333
```

Continue sroll:

```
xxx
111
222
333
444
```

That sometimes happens but I'm also seeing:

```
xxx
xyx
xxx
222
333
```

Or even:

```
xxx
xyx
xxx
(background color blank space)
111
222
```

It looks clearly disjoint.

Comment: "So I have two view controllers on one iOS page" No, you don't. A view controller is not something that appears in the interface. It's a controller, not a view.

Comment: Why don't you put the whole thing in one tableView?

Comment: @Jef so put the static page in a header? of the table view?

Comment: Sure. Put zero rows in section zero, and use its (section 0's) header view for the upper container.

Answer (score 0):

I have not coded this, but I have some ideas. Firstly I think you will have to hook onto the scroll views used by the table views. In each controller I would add overrides for `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods so you can detect the scrolling. Then in those methods, update the scroll view position of the other table view.

That would be my first approach.